# Needs some consulting regarding upgrading Angular 8 to latest

Tags: angular8, angular13

We need to upgrade a project built by angular 8.2, i was wonder if i could get some tips and explanations about the process:

- what are the risks - which blockers should i anticipate?
- what's the best practices - upgrading from one version to the next -
  or from 8 straight to latest?

the project contains the following libraries:

```
"@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.9.0",
"@angular/animations": "^8.2.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.1.3",
"@angular/common": "^8.2.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.2.2",
"@angular/core": "^8.2.2",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
"@angular/forms": "^8.2.2",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.2",
"@angular/router": "^8.2.2",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"angular2-moment": "^1.7.1",
"core-js": "^3.2.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"json-server": "^0.16.1",
"keycloak-angular": "^7.0.1",
"keycloak-js": "^6.0.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.1.9",
"primeicons": "^2.0.0",
"primeng": "^8.0.2",
"rxjs": "^6.5.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
"socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
"webpack-spritesmith": "^1.0.1",
"zone.js": "^0.10.2",
"ngx-mat-select-search": "1.8.0",
"ngx-toastr": "10.1.0",
"howler": "2.2.1",
"ngx-json-viewer": "^3.0.2",
"@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^2.0.3",
"@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^2.0.1",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
"xlsx": "0.12.12"
```

Comment: Please see https://update.angular.io/?v=8.2-13.0, I think it answers most of your questions. One possible risk could be that third party libraries are not compatible with Angular 13.

Comment: @JSONDerulo thanks - i'm familiar  with the document you referred to - i was asking more generally about the process and tried to tips of the handling any issues